# p5.Sound distorted on mobile?

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

I'm developing an experimental website which uses `p5.Sound` to analyze a certain song and I use the frequencies of this song to draw on a canvas.

The sound sounds great on my laptop & PC, but the problem is that when I try to listen to it on mobile, it starts to flicker, and it's slowed down (a lot...)

I've tried on other phones and it's the same.
Even on the official docs: https://p5js.org/examples/sound-sound-effect.html
It's laggy for a simple ring sound.

Does anyone experience this issue?
It's working fine if I use regular JavaScript and HTML `<audio>` elements.

Also, do you know others simple ways to get frequencies of a sound played from html `<audio>` elements?

Comment: I sadly have experienced this too :p p5.Sound uses the web audio api, that is build into your browser. This api needs a lot of resources to perform well and is incredibly dependant on hardware. Due to the high bitrate needed to process audio file (44100 times a second). Especially on mobile it struggles to keep up. I made a whole synthesizer based on the oscillator nodes; synth64.now.sh (smash some keys).

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution by looking at how p5.sound works.

I ended up using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).
I created an audio context then an analyzer and the sound was no longer distorted on mobile.
The process is almost the same as if you where using p5 :)